# Email Campaign Manager Reports?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore-ecm

I am working on Email Campaign Manager reports sections and I am unable to understand few things in reports.

- What is Value and how this Value generates for a message?
- Value per visit?
- Value per Email?
- Visit per email?

Please see attached screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this may not entirely answer your question, but from the [ECM Marketer's Guide](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/products/ecm/22/ecm_marketers_guide_22-a4.pdf) (page 16):

> **Value per sent email** – The average value that a message has generated.
>
> **Value per visit** – The value per visit this message generated.
>
> **Visits per email sent** – The average number of visits to the website that a message induced.

So that leads to the next logical question: What is "`value`"?  Value is something that you define from within Sitecore.  You score your content and assign value to it.  Content that is deemed more important for the business will have a higher value than content that is not as important.  When a user visits your site as a result of an ECM email, DMS tracks the visit and as they navigate around content that has value associated with it, the value is accumulated.

Check out the [Marketing Operations Cookbook](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/72/marketing_operations_cookbook_sc72-a4.pdf) for more information on assigning value to your content.

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Thanks Craig, yes I also found these things in same document but Value is not understandable in that document. But I think you are correct here I'll check in this document and let you know.

Comment: One other thing that this Value is Profile Value or Engagement Value Can you please confirm. I think this should be something profile values on page

Comment: Here's a very interesting post on engagement value, and what it actually is (and how to use it). http://www.sitecore.net/Learn/Blogs/Best-Practice-Blogs/Jill-Grozalsky/Posts/2014/05/Sitecore-DMS-Engagement-Values.aspx - that may answer your last question